# imported <Query> component is undefined with GraphQL and ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, graphql-tag

I am trying to render my HOC function in ReactJS, but it is giving me an error. Here are a few snippets (I have cut out the unrelated stuff for space and clarity):

In my `app.js` component I am importing my HOC as such:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../Home/Home";
import StoriesHOC from "../Story/GetAllStories/Stories";

export default class App extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route
          path="/all_stories"
          render={() => {
            return <StoriesHOC />;
          }}
        />
         </Switch>
       </div>
    </Router>
   );
 }
}
```

Then going into the `<StoriesHOC />`:

```
import React from "react";
import StoryShow from "../StoryShow/StoryShow";
import { Query, Fetching, Error } from "react-apollo";
import { getStories } from "../../Queries/Queries";

function Stories({ stories, getStoriesQuery }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="stories_header">
       <h2>All Stories</h2>
      </div>
     <div className="stories-container">
       {stories.map(story => (
         <StoryShow
          key={story.id}
          story={story}
          getStoriesQuery={getStoriesQuery}
      />
      ))}
     </div>
    </div>
   );
  }

 export default function StoriesHOC(props) {
   return (

   <Query query={getStories}>
  {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      console.log(data)
  if (error) return <Error />
  if (loading || !data) return <Fetching />

  return <Stories 
          {...props} 
          getStoriesQuery={getStories} 
          stories={(data && data.stories) || []}/> }}
  </Query>
 );
}
```

EDIT: Here is the StoryShow Component as it too is being exported as a default function.

```
  import React from "react";
  import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

  export default function StoryShow({
   story: {id, title, author, tagline, summary} = {}
   }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <h2>{tagline}</h2>
      <h3>{author}</h3>
      <p>{summary}</p>
      <Link exact to={'/story/' + id}>Read More</Link>
   </div>
  )
 }
```

The actual GraphQL query, `import { getStories } from "../../Queries/Queries";` is being carried out in another file and is formatted as such:

```
 import gql from "graphql-tag";

 export const getStories = gql`
   query getStories {
      stories {
        id
        title
        author
        tagline
      }
     }
   `;
```

However, the actual error displayed in the chrome browser is:

```
 Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) 
 or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You 
 likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, 
 or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

 Check the render method of `StoriesHOC`.
```

It later gives the line at where it stops which is `<Query query={getStories}>` seen earlier in the StoriesHOC function. **That being said, it would seem my issue is stemming from this line alone,** but while I've been all of the board with trying to solve the issue, my best guess is only that I am doing something wrong in my GraphQL query, however when I check the IDE in the backend, it renders perfectly.

There is also the issue of trying to figure out if I exported the imported the function properly in my app.js file, but I know that because I exported using the `export default function myFunc` that it should be imported as currently state.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as well as advice or critques. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Error seems to be JSX tag related - `StoryShow` is exported?

Comment: @xadm As far as I can tell, yes, I edited the post to show I was exporting it.

Comment: Remove all 'body' from `<Query/>` in `StoriesHOC` - render some html, simple `<div/> to check if it's related to child components or query. Queries can be directly imported from `*.graphql` files.

Comment: I did as you said, and the StoriesHOC component renders no problem. I believe my error is in the Query component at <Query query={getStories}>, because when I get the error in the browser, the debugger redirects me to that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem, it was an outdated npm installs for `react-apollo, graphql-tag, and apollo-boost.` It sounds pretty obvious that that should have been the first place that I looked, but I had literally just updated them two weeks ago!

For the people passing by, here is a snippet off the package versions that are working for me:

```
"dependencies": {
  "apollo-boost": "^0.1.15",
  "cors": "^2.8.4",
  "express": "^4.16.3",
  "graphql": "^0.13.2",
  "graphql-server-express": "^1.4.0",
  "graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
  "react": "^16.5.0",
  "react-apollo": "^2.1.11",
  "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
  "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**If** component with stripped code/content

```
export default function StoriesHOC(props) {
  return (
    <Query query={getStories}>
      {({ data }) => {
        console.log(data)
        return <div>fake content</div>
      }
    </Query>
  )
}
```

**renders correctly then query is OK and problems is in removed parts**. Recover them one by one to find/isolate **real** source of problems.

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps I did not mention it clearly enough. I know that the source of the error is the actual ```query={getStories}``` line in the ```<Query>``` component, so I know where the problem is, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: try to define `getStories` directly in the same file, w/o importing. This error usually is related to virtual tree/nodes/elements - not params/props.

Comment: I have done what you recommended, but the error still persists, I am fresh out of ideas at this point. Any recommendations? I can link my Github code if you like

Comment: try `getStories` w/o `query getStories {`

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Thank you for your help!

Comment: [import queries from files](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag#webpack-preprocessing-with-graphql-tagloader) - usable with fragments